# Worked examples of applying Ito's lemma

Tags: stochastic-calculus, reference-request, itos-lemma

In most textbooks [Ito's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ito's_lemma) is derived (on different levels of technicality depending on the intended audience) and then only the classic examples of [Geometric Brownian motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ito's_lemma#Geometric_Brownian_motion) and the [Black-Scholes equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ito's_lemma#Black.E2.80.93Scholes_formula) are given.

**My question**
I am looking for references where *lots* of worked examples of applying Ito's lemma are given in an easy to follow, step by step fashion. Also more advanced cases should be covered.

Comment: This post has been up for a while, is great, and helped me through understanding this topic more.

I also wanted to update it with additional resources that I found → http://www.math.drexel.edu/~song/Gene%20Golub%20Summer%20School/Song/Exercise%202.pdf

Comment: @Chef1075: Thank you for those additional resources.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

These are all examples on Ito Formula in its general form (with quadratic variations):

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: +1: Thank you, could you please also give a source

Comment: @vonjd Its lecture notes from a course on Mathematical Finance

Comment: @emcor Can I have this images in pdf file

Comment: @emcor Would be able to provide the URL to the lecture notes from this course?

Answer (score 6):

I thought this was an interesting example to add. It concerns a "ratio model" of habit (as opposed to a "difference" model of habit). See, for example, Abel (1990, American Economic Review). Let
$$
x_t = \lambda \int_{-\infty}^t e^{-\lambda(t-s)} c_s ds.
$$
(For context, $x_t$ is a log habit index that is given by a geometric average of past consumption, where $c_t$ is log consumption.)
Then by Ito's formula,
\begin{align}
d x_t &= \lambda \int_{-\infty}^t -\lambda e^{-\lambda(t-s)} c_s ds \, dt + \lambda c_t dt \\
  &= \lambda (c_t - x_t) dt.
\end{align}
The part that is interesting to me is the that it easy to err in thinking that the answer is $dx_t = \lambda c_t dt$ or $d x_t = -\lambda x_t dt$.

EDIT: Here, $c_s$ is some well-behaved stochastic process. This is essentially the same as 9-1 (a) above when $dc_t = dW_t$, where $W$ is a Brownian motion. This kind of calculation seems to show up somewhat frequently (Hull-White interest rate model), but doesn't seem to directly use Ito's lemma.

Comment: Where do you need Ito's lemma in this? Looks like plain Leibniz rule to me - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Formal_statement.

Comment: @LocalVolatility I've edited the answer to reflect your comment. I guess the point is that $c_t$ can be a stochastic process and the calculation still works out the same (example 9-1 (a) above). However, I can remove the answer entirely if you think that's best.

Comment: I think there is no harm in keeping it as your edit makes it clear that it doesn't directly invoke Ito's lemma.