# Clarification of Ito's lemma

Tags: itos-lemma, martingale

I was looking at the various examples provided in the discussion [Worked examples of applying Ito's lemma](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/14102/worked-examples-of-applying-itos-lemma)

**One such example is 9.1 (c). This states that -**

if $S_t =\! S_0 + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \mu_u S_u du + \int\limits_{0}^{t} \sigma_u S_u dW_u$ with $\mu=\left(\mu_t \right)_{t\geq0}, \sigma=\left(\sigma_t \right)_{t\geq0}, \int\limits_{0}^{T} |\mu_s| + |\sigma_s|^2 ds < \infty$. Then $\int\limits_{0}^{T} \sigma^2_s ds = -2\log \frac{S_T}{S_0} + \int\limits_{0}^{T} \frac{2}{S_u} dS_u$

Then it says $\frac{S_T}{S_0} = e^{\int\limits_{0}^{T} \sigma_s dW_s - \int\limits_{0}^{T} \left(0.5\sigma_s^2 - \mu_s \right) ds}$, which I understand the derivation.

I then failed to grasp the remaining part which shows that : $\log S_T - \log S_0 = \int\limits_{0}^{T} \frac{1}{S_u} dS_u -0.5 \int\limits_{0}^{T} \sigma_u^2 du$

**2nd example goes for 4. This states that -**

if $X_t =\! e^{W_t+0.5t} + e^{W_t-0.5t}$, then $dX_t =\! X_t dW_t + e^{W_t+0.5t}dt$.

To prove this, it is taken that $X_t=Z_tY_t, Z_t = e^{W_t-0.5t}, Y_t = e^t + 1$. It sates that the process $Z_t$ is continuous semi-martingale and $Y_t$ is continuous semi-martingale of bounded variation. Therefore it holds that $\left[ ZY \right]=0$. My questions are

1. Why $Z$ is continuous semi-martingale and $Y$ is continuous semi-martingale with bounded variation? What is required to prove them so?
2. How to show exactly that $\left[ZY\right] = 0$

Your pointer will be highly helpful

Answer (score 4):

**For the first one**, we have:

$$ dS_t = \mu_t S_t dt + \sigma_tS_t dW_t $$
and note that

$$ (dS_t)^2 = \sigma_t ^2 S_t^{2} dt. $$

We apply Ito formula to

$$ f(S_t) = \ln S_t. $$

As $f'(x) = x^{-1}$ and $f^{''}(x)= -x^{-2}$, we get:

$$ d \ln S_t  =   S_t^{-1}  dS_t  - 0.5 S_t^{-2} (dS_t)^2 $$

which is equivalent to

$$ d \ln S_t  =   S_t^{-1}  dS_t  - 0.5 \sigma_t^2 dt. $$

Integration from $0$ to $T$ gives:

$$ \ln S_T - \ln S_0 =  \int_0^T S_t^{-1}  dS_t  - 0.5 \int_0^T \sigma_t^2 dt. $$

**For the second one**:

A process has bounded variation if almost all its paths are functions with [bounded
variation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_variation).

This needs to be proven for $Y_t$.

For the rest of the questions, you can take as facts (proven in many books on stochastic calculus) that:

1. Ito processes are [continuous semimartingales](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semimartingale#Continuous_semimartingales) (with the two pieces, continuous local martingale and continuous finite variation process, visible).
2. [Finite variation processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_variation#Finite_variation_processes) (bounded variation on every finite time interval, with probability $1$) have $0$ quadratic variation.
3. The [quadratic covariation between a finite variation process and a continuous semimartingale](https://almostsure.wordpress.com/2010/01/19/properties-of-quadratic-variations/) is $0$.